# My Boolean evaluates to FALSE when I user an || OR or an && and in JAVA

Tags: java

The part

```
static boolean isBagFull = ((!Bag.itemSlot1.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot2.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot3.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot4.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot5.equals("Empty")));
```

always becomes FALSE! PLEASE HELP! although i checked all the itemSlots and they are all "Empty"

```
static Bag bag = new Bag();
static String helmet = "";
static String chestplate = "";
static String leggings = "";
static String boots = "";
static boolean isBagFull = ((!Bag.itemSlot1.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot2.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot3.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot4.equals("Empty"))||(!Bag.itemSlot5.equals("Empty")));


public void removeArmour(String s, int b){
    if (b==1&&!helmet.equals("")) {
        if (!isBagFull){//ITS USED HERE GUYS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! HELP!!!!!
            bag.newItem(s);
            helmet = "";
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have any room to remove the "+s);
        }
    }else if (b==2&&!chestplate.equals("")){
        if (!isBagFull){
            bag.newItem(s);
            chestplate = "";
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have any room to remove the "+s);
        }
    }else if (b==3&&!leggings.equals("")){
        if (!isBagFull){
            bag.newItem(s);
            leggings = "";
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have any room to remove the "+s);
        }
    }else if (b==4&&!boots.equals("")){
        if (!isBagFull){
            bag.newItem(s);
            boots = "";
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not have any room to remove the "+s);
        }
    }else if (b>=5||b<=0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry you don't have the correct position!", "ERROR", 0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Helmet = 1 \n Chestplate = 2 \n Leggings = 3 \n Boots = 4", "Armour Numbers", 0);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You ar not wearing anything there!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code to the Bag class, it's probably got a lot more to do with the issue than anything here.

Comment: Please learn to use arrays.  Any time you have variables named like `itemSlot1`, `itemSlot2`, `itemSlot3`, ..., that's a sign that you need to use an array instead of keeping all the variables separate.

Comment: Yeah I actually just started doing that a little bit after this post! Thank you!!
@ajb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all itemSlots are "Empty" your condition:

```
 ((!Bag.itemSlot1.equals("Empty"))
||(!Bag.itemSlot2.equals("Empty"))
||(!Bag.itemSlot3.equals("Empty"))
||(!Bag.itemSlot4.equals("Empty"))
||(!Bag.itemSlot5.equals("Empty")));
```

evaluates to:

```
 ((!"Empty".equals("Empty"))
||(!"Empty".equals("Empty"))
||(!"Empty".equals("Empty"))
||(!"Empty".equals("Empty"))
||(!"Empty".equals("Empty")));
```

which evaluates to:

```
 ((!true)
||(!true)
||(!true)
||(!true)
||(!true));
```

It should be obvious why it's always false :)

Assuming your bag is full if any one slot is not empty, you really want:

```
static boolean isBagFull = ((Bag.itemSlot1.equals("Empty"))||(Bag.itemSlot2.equals("Empty"))||(Bag.itemSlot3.equals("Empty"))||(Bag.itemSlot4.equals("Empty"))||(Bag.itemSlot5.equals("Empty")));
```

But if it's only full if all slots are not empty, you want:

```
static boolean isBagFull = ((Bag.itemSlot1.equals("Empty"))&&(Bag.itemSlot2.equals("Empty"))&&(Bag.itemSlot3.equals("Empty"))&&(Bag.itemSlot4.equals("Empty"))&&(Bag.itemSlot5.equals("Empty")));
```

Comment: Oh ok! That makes sense!